# If I visit Iran, is there a risk of not being allowed to enter the USA anymore?

Tags: usa, iran, swiss-citizens

I would like to visit Iran as a tourist but I'd also like to visit the USA some time after. I know the relations between the two countries are bad.

Is it likely that I'm not allowed to enter the USA after having been to Iran?

If it matters, I've never been to either of those countries. I'm a Swiss citizen, an atheist from a Christian background.

Comment: Almost certainly not. However, you *will* need to apply for a visa before your next visit to the USA. They're good for 10 years and, from anecdotal accounts I've read online, it seems vanishingly unlikely your visa will get declined solely on the basis of past tourist visits to nations designated state sponsors of terrorism

Comment: `anecdotal accounts I've read online, it seems vanishingly unlikely your visa will get declined solely on the basis of past tourist visits to nations designated state sponsors of terrorism ` On the contrary all the anecdotal online new I read implies it is incrementally more difficult and stressful after undertaking such a trip although not impossible at all.

Comment: I second Paul here. You will find yourself in a 900k+ name long list, pending review by the state department. A timely and transparent process it is not. I suspect the average treatment time quoted on the internet for people on that list dates from last year. They are seriously off. To give you an idea It already stopped me from having one business trip to the US a couple of months ago and it looks like it will impair another one in a couple of weeks.

Comment: @user189035 thank you for your feedback. I wasn't expecting it to be that hard. By the way isn't there some shortcuts when it involves business? Because if that's a problem, I don't want this trip to slow my career because of such limitation...

Comment: Accidentally, I satisfy both the family in the US and business motive exceptions. The point is your visa file has to be treated by the state department. It used to be a speedy process. But my experience does not concur. I had also read of anecdotal accounts that the process is   quick and hassle-free. I think those  accounts might be a bit dated at this point.

Comment: This is very anecdotal (hence a comment not an answer), but I spoke to someone recently who visited Iran then wanted to visit the US. Apparently he had to wait months to get an interview at the embassy. When he finally got there, the conversation was along the lines of: "So, why are you visiting the US?" "I'm going on holiday." "Oh. Why do you need a visa, then?" "Because I visited Iran." "Oh. Why did you visit Iran, then?" "I went on holiday." "Oh. That's fine, then."

Comment: Also anecdotal: I visited Iran, applied for a B2, got a visa interview within a week, was asked during the visa interview what I did in Iran an when I went there. Visa approved (10 year B1/B2) without any issue. Upon entry in the US not a single question was asked. If anything, my impression is that it makes life easier at the border. Because the burden moved to the visa application when they have all the time in the world to screen you. If for some reason they don't want to let you in they will simply refuse the visa instead of denying entry.

Comment: As a Swiss citizen who once/occasionally went there on holiday, you are extremely unlikely to be refused the visa. The much more likely effect you want to consider is that now you aren't eligible under the VWP, there might be a wait of some weeks/months between when you apply for the visa vs when you can travel. That might increase the price of your ticket (or else you just buy it upfront and worry about cancellation/rebooking in the event that becomes necessary).

Comment: Please clarify *"I'd also like to visit the USA some time after"*. Would that be a B1, B2 or some other class of visa (F? H?) ? Single-entry or multiple-entry? If you needed to go to an interview for the visa at your nearest US consulate in Switzerland (BE/GE/ZH), how inconveniencing is that?

Comment: @smci It's not specified because I still don't know and want it to be as open as possible. The one reason I'm sure is that I'll go multiple times for 2-3 weeks long tourism trips. However I'm an engineer and as such it's possible that one day I get an interesting job opportunity in the USA, although I don't have any reason to think it'll happen soon or I'd accept it. If I need an interview I can go anywhere in the country, at least Switzerland is small ;)

Comment: @TimF: if you simply want to come as a tourist (B1), that should be harmless. Whereas if you (say) wanted to business visit in something national-security-related, it might attract scrutiny, and cause delays. I don't know. Also the US admin changes its policies quite often.

Comment: Slightly related question: [USA visa with prior trip to Iran in previous passport: can I get away with omitting any mention of the Iran trip?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89815/usa-visa-with-trip-to-iran/100666#100666) Not that I'm endorsing the path suggested by that question.

Comment: Somewhat anecdotal - for some 15-20 Russian nationals who previously visited Iran, it caused no delays in getting B1/B2 visa. And, as far as I know, no one was asked any pressing questions about Iran.

Comment: Related question: [Is there any list of countries I should not visit if I want to go to the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/26725/1219)

Comment: The US will give you a hard time/make you wait when you want to come over here, but they'll let you in eventually, if your Iranian visit was benign. Honestly it's more likely to be jailed in Iran for being an atheist/apostate than be refused entry to the United States after visiting Iran.

Comment: @TylerH I know that freedom of speech (i.e. without putting one's life in danger or unwanted situations) is not as good in other countries as in Switzerland. Therefore I'm not going to show anything from me that would be badly received, either in Iran or in the USA. I want to go in those  countries to enjoy the places, the people, the culture, and for that no one needs to know what I believe or don't believe in and what are my political views. Now on that question I might lie for sure ;)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The main consequence of having visited Iran before going to the U.S. is that you are no longer eligible to travel on the Visa Waiver Program (VWP).

If you have travelled to or been present in Iran, Iraq, Libya, Somalia, Sudan, Syria, or Yemen on or after March 1, 2011, you will need to follow the regular process and apply for a visa at a U.S. Embassy or Consulate.

While not being able to travel on the VWP is a hassle, it is likely the only consequence. That you would not be able to visit the U.S. after Iran is improbable (given, of course, that there are no aggravating circumstances).

Source: https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html

See also this answer by Zach Lipton:

> Therefore, there is nothing that would prohibit you from coming to the
>   US. It is, of course, possible that you could receive extra
>   questioning at immigration, and if you're seen as a security risk, you
>   won't be admitted. That's always true whether or not you've visited
>   Iran though. A visa is never a guarantee of admission.

*From [I have a valid visa for the USA. I have visited Iran since it was issued. Can I still enter the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/64869/17071)*

See also [How long does the US Visa Waiver ban for people who travelled to Iran last?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76885/how-long-does-the-us-visa-waiver-ban-for-people-who-travelled-to-iran-last?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure but if I obtain a visa to the USA and then go to Iran, will I be able to to go to the USA during the next 10 years? That's the question of one or your links but there's no direct answer since the OP was not eligible for VWP.

Comment: @TimF with the same caveat as above (that a visa is not a guarantee of admission), then yes. Visiting Iran (or any of the other states mentioned) invalidates the VWP, not an existing visa.

Comment: @TimF In the worst-case scenario, you will be taken to secondary. They will waste your time and eventually let you go.

Comment: Any effect on non-visa, non-VWP countries like Canada?

Comment: How do they know I've visited Iran?

Comment: @lvella Probably by looking on the passport, or simply by asking. If the US authorities ask me this kind of thing, I prefer not to lie. Lying might be the best way to be rejected.

Comment: @silkroad that's a good question, you should ask it!

Answer (score 42):

I was in Iran in 2012, and in USA this summer(July, 2017).

First of all, my ESTA was denied(I'm an EU citizen). I had to show up at the US embassy of my country and pay a $200 fee for visa processing. It was accepted, but it doesn't really end there.

Landing at JFK, I was taken by homeland security to a room with a bunch of other people. They took my luggage and I had to stay for almost two hours(nearly missing my connecting flight to LAX!) with no explanation. No phones allowed, no bathroom breaks allowed, no communication from them at all. Extremely uncomfortable. The authorities were very rude in the process and offered no insight as to why I was held back. When engaging them constructively asking of a time horizon, I was told to shut up and sit down. Pretty much prison conditions.

Eventually, they just gave me a passport and grunted at me, and I had to basically sprint all across JFK to catch my flight.

So it doesn't close the door as to going to USA. However, you should consider if it's really worth it, because likely you'll receive the same treatment as above.

This is coming from a nordic looking male with a Scandinavian passport

Comment: Thanks for your experience. It's impressive how it seems to be different for each people, apparently with no real reason (I guess we could say Nordic people are not the ones the US should fear the most). I'm OK with going to the ambassy and paying to get a visa but the JFK part, that's another thing. Did they ask you some questions or you just had to wait ?

Comment: @TimF if you're worried about this, simply fly through the US preclearance facilities in Ireland. They won't be able to detain you in prison like conditions and you'll land in the US as if you're coming from a domestic flight.

Comment: They did not ask me anything, they had me waiting for no reason. If they wanted me to clarify something, that would've been better, because it seemed like intentional harassment for no benefit at all

Comment: @JonathanReez Thanks for the tip, that might be a good idea since the intra-Europeans flights are now often cheap. I'll look into that.

Comment: On behalf of the sane and civilized portion of the US, I'm really sorry that happened to you. It should not have.

Comment: "The authorities were very rude in the process", "I was told to shut up and sit down", "Pretty much prison conditions." -> wow, unbelievable! It makes me think, if these kind of behaviors are legal at all? Maybe, if people report these things to their representatives, it could prevent (or soften) future occurrences.

Comment: @Hatef You mean one's country representatives, thus not Americans? Not sure they can do much. Or do you mean the airport or US immigration representatives?

Comment: @JonathanReez Currently, a traveller undergoing preclearance has the right to change their mind and walk away. However, the US is pushing for a [Canadian bill that would give US preclearance officers the ability to detain travellers wishing to enter the US](http://www.parl.ca/DocumentViewer/en/42-1/bill/C-23/third-reading#enH645).

Comment: *"It's impressive how it seems to be different for each people, apparently with no real reason"* almost every visa/immigration issue is like that.

Comment: I shared an almost exact experience upon my second visit to USA. The staff as LAX told me my student visa status was not cleared when I exited USA last time during an exchange, which I found unbelievable as I exited USA normally. They detained me for two hours with almost the same treatment as the OP.

Comment: Wouldn't exactly call these prison-like conditions. I suspect you haven't lived very long in a country/culture where the normal conversation starter isn't "How may I help you today?" but rather "What do you want from me today?"... yes, it's rude, and you shouldn't have been treated that way, but there are places (no, not prisons) where people interact like this on a daily basis and still manage to live their lives. I hope you are treated better but I would also say that a thicker skin goes a long way toward helping yourself not feel awful.

Comment: @Mehrdad No, I live in a pretty civilized country. Being detained by armed officers in bulletproof vests, and having no access to communication OR even a bathroom is prison-like conditions for me. I don't really compare my expectation in fellow human beings to anything else than what I expect normally, just because I'm in another country. Decency isn't that hard.

Comment: @cbll: It's a big world out there. Welcome to the non-civilized world. =P

Comment: @TimF by representatives I was referring to consulates, lawyers, etc; however, as you said, it's highly unlikely they could do anything impressive! (SAD!)

Comment: About pre-clearance facilities: there are such in Canada too. I found the experience there much speedier and much more agreeable than on other occasions when I arrived directly. As an added bonus, when I travelled from Europe to New York connecting through Montreal the combined ticket was substantially cheaper than the direct flight.

Comment: @Hatef thanks, hopefully I'll not have to do that and everything will go well. By looking at the comments and answers it seems random but still uncommon to be badly treated.

Answer (score 3):

My daughter visited Iran (pure tourism) in 2013, and has been waiting 18 months without any news.  She was interviewed by the  USA Embassy in London.    My daughter is a UK citizen.

Comment: Hang in there. I got my US visa (a eu citizen) finally last week  after being ESTA and been on that waiting list for *2 years* (also after visiting iran for pure tourism). In light of the answers above, I'm not sure I plan to use said visa anytime soon tho.